# Program that translates a sentence into pig latin in Python

Tags: python

Here is my code down bellow. I'm having a hard time understanding how to manipulate each individual substring that I split from what the user has entered. The pig latin rules I'm following are adding 'ay' at the end of each word, and taking off whatever consonants are at the beginning of the word, and add them to the end. Here is an example:
Input: i love chicken
Output: iay ovelay ickenchay

```
consonant = 'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz'

ogSentence = input('Enter a sentence to be converted to pig latin: ')

wordList = ogSentence.split()

print (wordList)

for character in wordList:

    if (character in consonant):

        #bring character to the back of each word + 'ay'

    else:

        #add 'ay' to the end of each word
```

Any input would be greatly helpful!

Comment: please fix code formatting. It always surprises me that so many people post and not bother to even check what they posted

Comment: I'm sorry, the formatting looks fine on my end! I'm sorry if it comes out weird for you, I'm not sure what I could do to fix that :(.

Answer (score 1):

One option using [`itertools.takewhile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile) to move the consonants to the end and a generator expression:

```
from itertools import takewhile

consonant = set('bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz')
ogSentence = 'i love chicken'

def consonant_to_end(s):
    start = ''.join(takewhile(lambda x: x in consonant, s))
    return s[len(start):]+start
    
out = ' '.join(consonant_to_end(w)+'ay' for w in ogSentence.split())
```

Output: `'iay ovelay ickenchay'`

If you don't want to import `itertools`, you can also write yourself the `takewhile` logic:

```
def consonant_to_end(s):
    out = []
    for x in s:
        if x in consonant:
            out.append(x)
        else:
            break
    start = ''.join(out)
    return s[len(start):]+start
```

##### regex

Alternatively, using a regex:

```
import re

ogSentence = 'i love chicken'

out = re.sub(r'\b([bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]+)\b|([bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]*)([a-z]+)',
             r'\3\1\2ay', ogSentence, flags=re.I)
```

Output: `'iay ovelay ickenchay'`

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NnbJmc/1)

Answer (score 0):

I figured you don't understand how processing strings works in python

First you can iterate every character on a phrase like this

```
var = input('Input your text')
# You can iterate like this
for letter in var:
    print(letter)
# You can split by space, this should yield a list with just words
var_2 = var.split(' ')
# Then you can process your text
vocals =  ['a','e','i','o','u']
tmp_dict=[]
# we iterate over the words
for word in var_2:
    #check if the first letter is a consonant
    if word[0] not in vocals:
         tmp_dict.append(str(word[1:] + 'ay')
    else:
        tmp_dict.append(str(word+'ay'))
# We print the new phrase
print(' '.join(tmp_dict))
```

I think this should help you understand how to work with strings